# Can't call SSRS manager link from the browser

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I have configured Microsoft SQL Reporting Server. I have set my administrator user name and password in Service Account. All configuration is working well. But when I called server manager link from the browser, the authentication dialog box will be shown. I have set my Service Account username and password and login it. But I can't enter it. how can I enter? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to try, maybe.

**1 - Report Server permissions**

These are different than the Service Account permissions. By default, only the *BUILTIN\Administrators* group will have access to the Report Server. Is your user a server administrator?

If so, try accessing the Report Manager website through IE with **Run As Administrator**.

**2 - Authentication Dialog Box**

You can configure IE to pass your Windows user credentials automatically.

You need to look at the User Authentication permissions in IE configuration.

This link has more information: [Enter Credentials](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/878c6a48-892b-4c98-b0b4-3de55ab4f83a).

If these don't work you'll need to provide more information such as screenshots of the error messages, details of any errors in the logs, etc.